# Wifi file transfer from PC/CE Device to Android device

Tags: android, wifi, telnet, file-transfer

Is it possible to transfer a file from a CE device/PC to an android device running a Telnet client via Wifi? Is there any other method for file transfer to an Android device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telnet didn't help with the problem. I solved the issue by adding a FTP server to the CE device and corresponding FTP client in my android device using Apache common nets library.

Comment: Indeed.  It is actually with some effort possible to tunnel file data through a telnet session, but it's really not designed for that purpose, while (S)FTP is.